# Close Flash Player from FlashDevelop IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flashdevelop

Whenever I compile my project using FlashDevelop in 'Debug' the Flash Player window remains after I have clicked the 'Stop' button in Flash Develop. I have to then switch over to the flash player, click through any error messages and then close the player, which wastes a lot of time in the long run.

Any way to make it so Flash Player closes when I click 'Stop' in the Flash Develop debug tools?

**EDIT:**

My setup is a fresh install of Windows 7, a new copy of Flash Develop 4 and Flash Player 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FlashDevelop/Settings/ToolBar.xml just put this line

```
<button label="Kill FlashPlayer" click="RunProcess" tag="taskkill;/f /t /im FlashPlayerDebugger.exe" image="197" />
```

and restart FD.

Answer (score 6):

You may disable the error popup in your Flash Player by editing your mm.cfg file (which is in your Windows' user folder). Just add the following:

```
SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1
```

Then the Flash Player will nicely be killed when you stop FlashDevelop debugging. BTW, you will still be able to read the errors in the trace.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip! We are halfway there since the dialog boxes no longer pop up, but the Flash Player still sticks around after I hit the stop button.

Comment: Have you tried other test modes in project/properties/Test Movie? Such as new tab, popup or external player?

Comment: The project settings are 'external' by default, so external is the one with the problem. When I tried 'new tab' and 'popup', I lose all the debug functionality (breakpoints, stop, step through).

Comment: Do you have the debug version of the Flash Player ActiveX (the one used by Internet Explorer and these two modes)?

Comment: I do have the FP mentioned, the same one suggested by the FD team on their install page. Just to check, this works for you Kodiak?

Comment: To be honest, I always debug in firefox or in adl (which is closed by FD) so I'm just making blind guesses, sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Thinking of using air just for development to get adl :\

Answer (score 1):

I've asked this question in the Flash Develop forums and an admin informed me that this is a feature that they are currently thinking about including but that it FD cannot close the Flash Player atm.

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=8442&sid=be1affc07163323a49000722e6b86ce1&p=39291#p39291